# PC crash Event ID 41 (63)

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, kernel

I played overwatch during open beta and for the first week or two after release with no problem, however now whenever I'm playing usually in the menus my PC will reset. My event viewer shows Event 41 Kernal-Power and reads; The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

I sent my PC back to the manufacture as i suspected the psu as the problem but they tested the psu, gpu, ram, motherboard, hard drive, and both the cache and video memory and found no problems.

I have completely uninstalled both overwatch and all blizzard games/files and then reinstalled them. I have performed a factory restart on my PC, I have ensured all drivers are up to date and also completely uninstalled my nvidia drivers and installed an older set of drivers from when it was working without problems. I have also performed a stress test and memtest and had no problems. I have monitored the temps of my gpu and cpu when the crash occured and they seemed fine (around 70C). Nothing I'm using is overclocked as far as I'm aware.

This only occurs when playing overwatch I've had no problems with other games including LoL or GTA V.

CPU: Intel Core i5-4460
Motherboard: Z87M Gaming (MS-7866) (bios v1.5)
RAM: 2x 4GB Kingston HyperX Fury DDR3
GPU: NVIDEA GeForce GTX 970 (drivers: 368.81)
PSU: Corsair S Series VS450 450 Watt Power Supply
OS: Windows 8.1 x64

Any other information you need please just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back your drivers? NVIDIA drivers are notorious for causing crashes on some games, and not on others. In addition, to be quite honest, your PSU seems a bit lacking. Are you sure 450 is enough for your system?

Comment: From a battery calculating website (CoolerMaster AND Newegg), from just putting in your CPU, GPU and RAM, recommended PSU is 550+. You may want to look into something a little more beefy.

Comment: check the steps from this KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick responses. Kaizerwolf i have tried rolling back my drivers to when the game played with no problems, but the problem persisted. Magiccandre1981 i have checked the steps in the article provided and have tried everything on there, also the Bugcheckcode is 0 if that is any help. Also i would like to apologise im not the most computer savvy person could someone explain why it would work playing overwatch for nearly a month with no problem if it was the psu?

Comment: Also is there a way to check if its the psu other than getting a new one, as i dont have the money right now. Thanks again.